# Simulating balls falling into a mesh. Why do I get different results each time?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation

So basically I've an array of about 700-800 spheres that will fall into a box. What I am trying to do is, after the balls settle they spell out something. I did that,by going to the last frame of the animation and selected some of the balls and colored them differently so that I get my text. But when I went back to my first image and rendered the animation, the last frame is not the same as I had made it. Is there something I should try doing or is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bake your simulation before you colour them. This way they will keep the lock down your simulation so it wont change. This also helps speeding up the play back since it no longer needs to solve the simulation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. It worked exactly how I wanted to.